# How do I convert a SCSS hex value to a string so can be used for a CSS class name?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I have a lot of SCSS variables such as:

```
$blue:    #007bff !default;
$indigo:  #6610f2 !default;
$purple:  #6f42c1 !default;
$pink:    #e83e8c !default;
$red:     #dc3545 !default;
```

Is it possible to convert the value of `$blue` to a string? so it would be:

```
$blue: "007bff";
```

At the moment I am having to do this:

```
$blue:    #007bff !default;

$primary:       $blue !default;
$primary-hex:   "007bff";

$theme-colors: () !default;
$theme-colors: map-merge((
  "primary":      $primary,
  $primary-hex:   $primary
), $theme-colors);
```

The reason for this is because I want to use it as part of a variable name (I know... not good practice but is needed because our CMS spits out hex values and they need to be used as classes.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer, hopefully this will help anyone else:

```
$theme-colors: () !default;
$theme-colors: map-merge((
  "primary":    $primary,
  str-replace(#{$primary}, '#', '') :    $primary
), $theme-colors);
```

The key bit being the `#{}`.

The `str-replace` function is:

```
@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);

  @if $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
  }

  @return $string;
}
```

Comment: For me it was `$color: str-slice(#{$color}, -6);` but your answer helped me a lot.